# M2: Long delay before a new order appears in admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, orders, indexing

Im wondering if anybody else has experienced a long delay (like 5-20 minutes) between the time an order is placed, and the time the order appears in the admin panel (also, the emails only get delivered once it appears). It seems like the orders are queuing up, but I'm not aware of an order queue mechanism.

Could this also be a delayed indexing problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late email come because of : `Store > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > General Settings >  Asynchronous sending > Enable.`

Late come order in admin grid because of : `Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid settings > Asynchronous Indexing > Enable`

And enabling both make Place order faster.